# nodejs-javascript update object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to nodejs and trying to write a function to update and object on mongodb.
Here is my fundtion that is under routs/rates.js. Briefly, the function is called whenever a button/link called "like" is clicked and it should update the total number of like this item has recieved. Item is an object in my mongodb.

```
router.put('/update_likes', function (req, res) {
var sessionId = req.sessionID;
var queryId = req.body.queryId;
var item = req.body.item;
var itemId= req.body.itemId;
var commentsNum= req.body.commentsNum;
var category= req.body.category;

var find_condition = {
    'item': item,
    'sessionId': req.sessionID,
    'category': category,
    'commentsNum': commentsNum
};

var update_callback = function (err, item_obj) {
    if (err)
        return console.log('An error occurred: ', err);
    var update = {
        $inc: { 'totalLikes': 1 },
        $push: {
            'likes': {
                'itemId': itemID,
                'sequence': item_obj.totalLikes + 1
            }
        }
    };
    Query.update(find_condition, update, function (err) {
        if (err)
            return console.log('[UPDATE] ', err);
    });
}
Query.findOne(find_condition, update_callback);
res.sendStatus(200);});
```

Using the function above, gives me an error that totalLikes is undefined in line 15. What I understant is that I cannot use item_obj inside var update = {}, but I actually don't know how to solve this issue in another way.

Any hints? or suggested enhancements to the code?

Comment: I think you should check if the db query is returning an object before trying to update it.

Comment: And if the query doesn't find any object, shouldn't you return an error in the request response, instead of 200?